# Emacs with nice page break lines?

Tags: emacs, page-break

Under Emacs, how to get nice page-break-lines like these?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [page-break-lines](https://github.com/purcell/page-break-lines) package, then:

```
M-x turn-on-page-break-lines-mode
```

To insert a new page break line: `C-q C-l`
(this inserts a ^L char in your buffer)

You can also easily jump to next/previous page break using `C-x [` or `C-x ]`

Answer (score 1):

Library [Pretty Control-L](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettyControlL) lets you do that.  You can easily customize the appearance of a page-break (aka line feed, aka `Control-l` character).
The library is [`pp-c-l.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/pp-c-l.el).

Mode `pretty-control-l-mode` turns the display on and off.

You have these user options and face, which you can customize:

- `pp^L-^L-string` - Highlighted string displayed in place of each Control-l (`^L`) character.
- `pp^L-^L-string-pre` - String displayed just before `pp^L-^L-string`.
- `pp^L-^L-string-post` - String displayed just after `pp^L-^L-string` (empty by default).
- `pp^L-^L-string-function` - Function to produce string displayed in place of a Control-l (`^L`) char.  If the option value is non-`nil`, option `pp^L-^L-string` is not used.
  You can use this option to have a dynamically defined display string.
  For example, this value displays a window-width horizontal line:

  ```
  (lambda (win) (make-string (1- (window-width win)) ?_))
  ```
- `pp^L-highlight` (a face, not a variable) - Face used to highlight `pp^L-^L-vector`.